# superposition versus statistical mixture interpretation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have an interpretation problem here. It is about the coherent state

$$\left|\left.\alpha,\frac{\pi}{2\Omega}\right.\right\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}}\mid\alpha\rangle+e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\mid-\alpha\rangle\right)$$

The properties of this state are now studied in a "macroscopic" situation, $|\alpha|\gg1$ and $\alpha=i\rho$
 .
The wavefunctions are

$$\Psi_{\alpha}\left(x\right)=Ce^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-\alpha\sqrt{2}\right)^{2}}$$

and

$$\Psi_{\alpha}\left(p\right)=C\text{´}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(p-i\alpha\sqrt{2}\right)^{2}}.$$

Now one calculates the propìbability distribution and finds out:

$$P\left(x\right)\varpropto e^{-x^{2}}\cos^{2}\left(x\rho\sqrt{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
and
$$P\left(p\right)\simeq e^{-\left(p-\rho\sqrt{2}\right)^{2}}+e^{-\left(p+\rho\sqrt{2}\right)^{2}}$$

If one types this into wolfram alpha for $\rho = 5$ one finds interference fringes for $P(x)$ and 2 Gaussian peaks for $P(p)$.

From these facts it should be visible that whereas in $k$ space the 2 microscopic separated peaks are visible (as it is supposed to be) if $\alpha$ is pure imaginary and $\rho$ is macroscopic, the interference fringes in $x$ space are practically not visible.

My question is now why these fringes are not visible? I see them for $\rho=5$?

Comment: I can probably help you here but I don't understand some of your notation. In the first equation, what is $\Omega$ and why does it not appear on the right side of the equation? What is $\rho$?